# R: Make this loop faster using sapply

Tags: r, for-loop, sapply

I'm very new in R and i'm trying to figure it out how to make my function faster using sapply, any help?

```
x <- c(0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.7)
y <- c(10.0, 7.0, 5.5, 4.5, 3.2, NA)
z <- c(as.data.frame(cbind(x,y))


vcub=function(y, x, z) 
{
    vol<-vector()
    for(i in 1:dim(z)[1]){
        if(is.na(y[i]))
        {
          vol[i]<-(((pi*y[i-1]^2)/40000)/3)*(x[i]-x[i-1])
        }else{
          vol[i]<-(((pi*y[i-1]^2) + (pi*y[i]^2))/80000)*(x[i]-x[i-1])
        }
    }
    return(as.data.frame(vol))
}
```

Comment: Is `sapply` is a requirement, or do you just want it faster in general?

Comment: @GSee Well, i'm trying to understand apply actually, but if there is other ways to make it faster, i would like to see it too.

Comment: Who told you `apply` is faster than `for` loop?

Comment: @DavidArenburg My professor. He said that dealing with a matrix is a faster and better way than a loop.

Comment: Well, first you should make order in your function. You are passing y,x,z and z already contains y and x, then you evaluate the arguments to get again y, x from z... totally confusing (and probably useless)...

Comment: Dealing with matrix is indeed better than with loop, but `apply` is also a loop. Have nothing to do with matrices

Comment: *apply-family functions are usually faster than loop because in loops you append to vectors (so a lot of vectors copies are destroyed and rebuilt). If you pre-allocate the vector this advantage usually disappears...

Comment: @digEmAll Now that you mentioned i realized the stupid example i gave. It's because i will use a data frame to obtain the values of x,y,z. That's why i am using the eval, i just forgot to take it out from the example.

Comment: @DavidArenburg I didn't know that. My professor said that apply was a way in R to deal with matrices. Is there any material you indicate about this function?

Comment: @somoto: also, your loop code is not correct. The first loop i=1, but you use `y[i-1]` and `x[i-1]` going out of the vector bounds (indexing in R is 1-based)

Comment: For this specific task, it seems that you need neither `for` of `_apply`; something like the following should get what you want `ifelse(is.na(y[-1]), (((pi * y[-length(y)]^2) / 40000) / 3) * diff(x), (((pi * y[-length(y)]^2) + (pi * y[-1]^2)) / 80000) * diff(x))` (perhaps `.[-1]` and `.[-length(.)]` are misplaced)

Comment: @digEmAll I forgot to mention, but the first row should return NA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can vectorize this code by replacing your `if` and `else` statements in the for loop with an `ifelse` statement and using vectorized arithmetic in R:

```
data.frame(vol=ifelse(is.na(y), pi*c(NA, head(y, -1)^2)/120000*c(NA, diff(x)),
                      pi*(y^2 + c(NA, head(y, -1)^2))/80000*c(NA, diff(x))))
#            vol
# 1           NA
# 2 0.0058512163
# 3 0.0031121402
# 4 0.0019831304
# 5 0.0011973395
# 6 0.0004557404
```

In general, it's easy to vectorize a computation when you can compute the i^th index of your result without using any of the previous indices you computed. Since your formula for `vol[i]` didn't depend on any of the previous `vol` values, you can just use basic arithmetic operators.